# Easiest way to create layer filled with image pattern in cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d v3 which has easy to access functionality to create CCSprites (images), CCDrawNode (primitives) and other types of layer like objects.

But I haven't found examples how to create simple layer (i.e. 100x100px) which filled by smaller image (i.e. 4x4px).

What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CCTexture* texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"bg.png"];

CCSprite *bgNode = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture
                                          rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _rootNode.contentSize.width, _appCtrl.winSize.height)];
bgNode.position = ccp(bgNode.contentSize.width / 2.0f, bgNode.contentSize.height / 2.0f);
ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
[bgNode.texture setTexParameters:&params];
```

In Cocos2d v3 Unit Tests sources I have found another way to solve this problem.

Note: you must do

```
#import "CCTexture_Private.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you would consider this the easiest way, but I think it is the fastest from a performance point of view:

Subclass `CCNode` and implement `-(void)draw`. Inside draw you can make custom openGL calls, bind a texture with `GL_REPEAT` as parameter and draw it.

You can find a good Intro and examples to openGL-es here: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.de/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html

The easiest way I can think of btw would be to have some for loops creating millions of CCSprites filling the screen. But I wouldn't recommend that ;)